# Property 'delegate' with type 'GameDelegate?' cannot override a property with type SKSceneDelegate?' XCODE SWIFT SCENEKIT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hey I have a HUD/OverlayScene that basically just displays the buttons. so now im trying to get this Delegate/GameDelegate to simply not have this error. Please look at the image on the bottom

Code:

```
   import iAd
   import simd
   import UIKit
   import GLKit
   import GameKit
   import SceneKit
   import StoreKit
   import SpriteKit
   import QuartzCore
   import Foundation
   import AVFoundation
   import AudioToolbox
   import GameController

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
extension GameViewController: GameDelegate {
func Kick() {
    print("Runnnnnnnininig")
    //-----Animate-Guy-----Working-Perfectly-----------
    let KickAnimation = CAAnimation.animationWithSceneNamed("art.scnassets/The1Anima.dae")!
    Guy.addAnimation(KickAnimation, forKey: "Go")
    Guy.removeAnimationForKey("Go", fadeOutDuration: 3.0)
  }
 }

 protocol GameDelegate {
 func Kick()
}

class HUD: SKScene {
var delegate: GameDelegate?
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't override this property. Give a new name for your delegate. For example gameDelegate

Comment: Awesome thanks for that it worked!